# Unresolved reference in Python when using function and for loop

Tags: python, reference

Can someone please explain why this doesnt work in Python and how can I make it work? I dont wanna do sa=0 or something first because this code is placed inside a function and I dont want sa to start with 0 each time the function executes.

```
    def tr(ok):

    s = 1
    sa = sa + (ok / s)
    print (sa)

for i in range(10):
    ok = 2
```

The error I get is that sa is a unresolved reference

EDIT: sa += (ok/s) doesnt work either

Comment: `sa` isn't defined before the line `sa = sa + (ok / s)` (also what are you trying to do in this line?)

Comment: You need to initialize `sa` before reading it. Also, your indentation in the post is not that clean. please fix it.

Comment: `sa` needs to be a global variable or a parameter to `tr`. Either way, you need to initialize it before/when you call `tr`.

Comment: What is the point of the `for` loop? And if `s = 1`, then `(ok / s)` also seems pointless.

Answer (score 1):

> The error I get is that sa is a unresolved reference

The reason this happens is due to local scope. When executing your tr function, only variables either passed **into** the function, declared as a global variable, or declared **in** the function are seen and used.

```
def tr(ok):
    s = 1
    sa = sa + (ok / s)
    print (sa)
```

In your code, the variables are:

- ok
- s
- sa

The computer can't finish assigning a value to sa because it needs sa to already have a value assigned in order to calculate the value of sa. If I gave you a math problem stating X+1 and asked you what the result of that would be, you'd be unable to because I never told you what X *is* in the first place. So here's what you should do:

Declare what sa is supposed to be inside the function:

```
sa = *something that the computer can set sa equal to*
sa + (ok / s)
```

Pass the value into the function by modifying *both* the function call and the function definition:

```
def tr(ok, sa):
```

Or declare sa as a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

if you are willing to take a result of a function you should use return(var_nam), anyway we don't understand what you want from your code.
the full code or a bittere expelnation can help us help you